# Unhandled Exception in Script when running PyGame in .exe?

Tags: python, pygame, exe

I have been trying to export my python code (with PyGame) into an executable. It worked, but when I run it, it tells me of an error.

It says:

```
Unhandled exception in script
Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception: No module named 'pygame'
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
   import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module name 'pygame'
```

I already tried to install PyGame but it still does not work. I am using Python 3.9.6. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: verify that you have installed pygame and try 'python -m PyInstaller <options> xxx.py --hidden-import pygame'

Comment: You should post the text of the error instead of an image. This allows the error to be searchable by others.

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).

Comment: @blackbrandt, Sorry, I'm new. I have changed it now. True apologies for any inconvenience caused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use auto-py-to-exe. This works unfailingly for me and avoids any issues while dealing with the messy command line. Rather than a command, this is a GUI interface which is easy to control and works every time. This can be installed with the command `pip install auto-py-to-exe`, and is simply ran with the command `auto-py-to-exe`. Once it opens the GUI, it should be self explanatory. You can use the Onefile option to make your exe wither one file or a directory, and you can add files that your code needs such as fonts or images. If you want more information you can go to the PyPI project page [here](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/).